# 'jQuery' is not defined no-undef

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I have a file that is using jQuery and it is only for testing purpose:

```
(function($) {
  "use strict"; // Start of use strict
  // Configure tooltips for collapsed side navigation
  $('.navbar-sidenav [data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    template: '<div class="tooltip navbar-sidenav-tooltip" role="tooltip" style="pointer-events: none;"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner"></div></div>'
  })
  // Toggle the side navigation
  $("#sidenavToggler").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("body").toggleClass("sidenav-toggled");
    $(".navbar-sidenav .nav-link-collapse").addClass("collapsed");
    $(".navbar-sidenav .sidenav-second-level, .navbar-sidenav .sidenav-third-level").removeClass("show");
  });
  // Force the toggled class to be removed when a collapsible nav link is clicked
  $(".navbar-sidenav .nav-link-collapse").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("body").removeClass("sidenav-toggled");
  });
  // Prevent the content wrapper from scrolling when the fixed side navigation hovered over
  $('body.fixed-nav .navbar-sidenav, body.fixed-nav .sidenav-toggler, body.fixed-nav .navbar-collapse').on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
    var e0 = e.originalEvent,
      delta = e0.wheelDelta || -e0.detail;
    this.scrollTop += (delta < 0 ? 1 : -1) * 30;
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  // Scroll to top button appear
  $(document).scroll(function() {
    var scrollDistance = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (scrollDistance > 100) {
      $('.scroll-to-top').fadeIn();
    } else {
      $('.scroll-to-top').fadeOut();
    }
  });
  // Configure tooltips globally
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
  // Smooth scrolling using jQuery easing
  $(document).on('click', 'a.scroll-to-top', function(event) {
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: ($($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top)
    }, 1000, 'easeInOutExpo');
    event.preventDefault();
  });
})(jQuery); // End of use strict
```

and  webpack complains:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/SbAdmin/js/sb-admin.js
  Line 45:  'jQuery' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

I added `jquery`  into `index.js` already but why it still complains?
I create my reactjs app with https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app.
The `index.js` looks as following:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

/* Import css */
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';
import './index.css';

/* Import javascript */
import 'bootstrap';
import 'jquery';
import './SbAdmin/js/sb-admin';

import App from './App/AppContainer.bs';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

As you can see `jQuery` is imported.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you importing jQuery from someplace? It's complaining because the end of your function you are passing jQuery to be used as $ inside the function. Without importing it I assume you have it as a global in which case you might need to add a `// eslint-disable-line no-undef`

Comment: I update my post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your file that you are using jQuery just include the line

```
import jQuery from 'jquery'
```

With that you don't need to have it included in the app.js file only the files for which you are using it.